# setting node's http.request timeout

Tags: node.js, timeout

I'm testing a server and I need to keep alive some connection as long as possible. I would like to set by hand the timeout of `http.request()` function. This is what I do in my code.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            //do something with chunk
        });
});
```

I tried something like `req.on('socket' function(socket){ socket.setTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);  });` but it gives me some strange errors and I think it's not the right way to do it. For your info the error I get using that approach is the following

```
Trace: 
    at Socket.<anonymous> (events.js:133:17)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/path/server_nologs.js:168:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at Array.1 (http.js:1250:9)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

Which is kinda cryptic to me. Can someone explain me how to set the timeout? Otherwise, if my approach is correct, how can I avoid getting that error?

Comment: Have you tried [req.setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback)?

Comment: Just tried. It seems like it doesn't even start the connection (I'm trying to connect it to another nodejs server, and the other server is not logging any connection to it).

Comment: I noticed that I had some error outside the boundaries of this question, I corrected them and now the server is working, but it still times out after a while. I guess it's the server I'm contacting and not this one. Do you know how to set a timeout also on the other side? It's still a nodejs server as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'm using: (works for me)

```
req = httpClient.request(urlParts.method, urlParts.path, urlParts);
req.connection.setTimeout(HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
```

where HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT is a var I declared before set to 30000

Comment: Thanks, I already found an answer similar to yours, but you're using `httpClient.request` and I don't know how dissimilar is that from my implementation! Anyway +1 thanks :-)

Comment: This sets the connection timeout not the request timeout. Closing a request doesn't strictly mean closing a connection.